# Make indexed content available to search by a group of people

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results, crawling, sharepoint-search

I have a couple of non-SharePoint, web-based systems (a MediaWiki and a Request Tracker ticketing system) with content that I want to have indexed by SharePoint Enterprise Search, but the results should only be visible to a group of people in IT. The wiki currently has no authentication, but access to it is restricted to users in a certain subnet. The ticketing system uses authentication, so I want to have SharePoint Search authenticate to it while indexing.

The most important part is that regular users searching in SharePoint should NOT see results from these two systems, just like with security-trimmed regular SharePoint content.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

It can as long as you figure out the authentication. We did it for MediaWiki by creating a Query Time Security Trimmer. It worked well, but does slow the delivery of results. The final solution was to turn on AD authentication. For the ticket system it should not be  problem.